# wordpress Default jquery not run for this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i want run wordpress jquery but not run by default jquery in wordpress core
but run with other source code how to solve this problem?

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'el_script');
function el_script(){

wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/js/bootstrap.min.js',array( 'jquery' ),'1.0.0',true );
}
```

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
let search_icon = $("#search-icon");
let search_form = $('#search-form > :input[type=search]');
search_icon.on('click', function () {
    search_form.toggleClass("search-active")
})
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: add one more enque statement before bootstrap which links to jQuery which you would like to add with different id like jQuery-new.  `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-new',
'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js','','3.3.1',true )`

Comment: i will use default jquery wp